# html dom parse - can i find only file types?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

While parsing the contents of a page I want to just list images, but, would rather find them by file extension as I might only want jpg and not png for example.

I know I can do this to list all images from within src tags but I want just the image as detailed above:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
```

I have read online docs but can find no mention of how/if that can be done?

**UPDATE**

This is the code i currently use:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

function getUrlAddress()
{
/*** check for https is on or not ***/
$url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
/*** return the full address ***/
return $url .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $e) // here I want to find just e.g. .jpg OR .png files instead of <img>

echo '<img src='.$e->src .'><br>';
```

Comment: Please add more information. Where does the page or the images come from?

Comment: can use https://gist.github.com/1358174 and this XPath instead: `//img[contains(@src,'.jpg')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$jpgs = $html->find('img[src$=jpg]');
```

Comment: We also need all images within backgrounds, like background-image:url(); or background:url();.